# reticulate can not find systemwide installed python package

Tags: python, r, reticulate

I am on Fedora 38 linux and I have systemide installations of matplotlib (python3-matplotlib). However, I can not seem to be able to find it using reticulate. I tried:

```
library(reticulate)
mp <- import("matplotlib")
Error in py_module_import(module, convert = convert) : 
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'
Error in py_module_import(module, convert = convert) : 
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'
Run `reticulate::py_last_error()` for details.
> reticulate::py_last_error()

── Python Exception Message ────────────────────────────────────────────────────
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/R/library/reticulate/python/rpytools/loader.py", line 119, in _find_and_load_hook
    return _run_hook(name, _hook)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib64/R/library/reticulate/python/rpytools/loader.py", line 93, in _run_hook
    module = hook()
             ^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib64/R/library/reticulate/python/rpytools/loader.py", line 117, in _hook
    return _find_and_load(name, import_)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'

── R Traceback ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
    ▆
 1. └─reticulate::import("matplotlib")
 2.   └─reticulate:::py_module_import(module, convert = convert)
```

What am I doing wrong?

```
Sys.which("python")
                                             python 
"$HOME/.virtualenvs/r-reticulate/bin/python"
```

which leads to: `python3.11`

Note that I do not have a problem with importing sys:

```
main <- import_main()
sys <- import("sys")
```

Then

```
names(sys$modules)
  [1] "sys"                             "builtins"                       
  [3] "_frozen_importlib"               "_imp"                           
  [5] "_thread"                         "_warnings"                      
  [7] "_weakref"                        "_io"                            
  [9] "marshal"                         "posix"                          
 [11] "_frozen_importlib_external"      "time"                           
 [13] "zipimport"                       "_codecs"                        
 [15] "codecs"                          "encodings.aliases"              
 [17] "encodings"                       "encodings.utf_8"                
 [19] "_signal"                         "_abc"                           
 [21] "abc"                             "io"                             
 [23] "__main__"                        "_stat"                          
 [25] "stat"                            "_collections_abc"               
 [27] "genericpath"                     "posixpath"                      
 [29] "os.path"                         "os"                             
 [31] "_sitebuiltins"                   "_distutils_hack"                
 [33] "types"                           "importlib._bootstrap"           
 [35] "importlib._bootstrap_external"   "warnings"                       
 [37] "importlib"                       "importlib._abc"                 
 [39] "itertools"                       "keyword"                        
 [41] "_operator"                       "operator"                       
 [43] "reprlib"                         "_collections"                   
 [45] "collections"                     "_functools"                     
 [47] "functools"                       "contextlib"                     
 [49] "importlib.util"                  "importlib.machinery"            
 [51] "google"                          "google.logging"                 
 [53] "site"                            "enum"                           
 [55] "numpy._globals"                  "numpy.__config__"               
 [57] "numpy._distributor_init"         "__future__"                     
 [59] "_sre"                            "re._constants"                  
 [61] "re._parser"                      "re._casefix"                    
 [63] "re._compiler"                    "copyreg"                        
 [65] "re"                              "_json"                          
 [67] "json.scanner"                    "json.decoder"                   
 [69] "json.encoder"                    "json"                           
 [71] "numpy._version"                  "numpy.version"                  
 [73] "math"                            "_datetime"                      
 [75] "datetime"                        "numpy.core._multiarray_umath"   
 [77] "numpy.compat._inspect"           "fnmatch"                        
 [79] "ntpath"                          "errno"                          
 [81] "urllib"                          "ipaddress"                      
 [83] "urllib.parse"                    "pathlib"                        
 [85] "_struct"                         "struct"                         
 [87] "_compat_pickle"                  "_pickle"                        
 [89] "pickle"                          "numpy.compat.py3k"              
 [91] "numpy.compat"                    "numpy.core.overrides"           
 [93] "numpy.core.multiarray"           "numpy.core.umath"               
 [95] "numbers"                         "numpy.core._string_helpers"     
 [97] "numpy.core._dtype"               "numpy.core._type_aliases"       
 [99] "numpy.core.numerictypes"         "numpy.core._exceptions"         
[101] "collections.abc"                 "_contextvars"                   
[103] "contextvars"                     "numpy.core._ufunc_config"       
[105] "numpy.core._methods"             "numpy.core.fromnumeric"         
[107] "numpy.core.shape_base"           "numpy.core.arrayprint"          
[109] "numpy.core._asarray"             "numpy.core.numeric"             
[111] "numpy.core.defchararray"         "numpy.core.records"             
[113] "numpy.core.memmap"               "numpy.core.function_base"       
[115] "numpy.core._machar"              "numpy.core.getlimits"           
[117] "numpy.core.einsumfunc"           "numpy.core._multiarray_tests"   
[119] "numpy.core._add_newdocs"         "numpy.core._add_newdocs_scalars"
[121] "numpy.core._dtype_ctypes"        "_ast"                           
[123] "ast"                             "_ctypes"                        
[125] "ctypes._endian"                  "ctypes"                         
[127] "numpy.core._internal"            "numpy._pytesttester"            
[129] "numpy.core"                      "numpy.lib.mixins"               
[131] "numpy.lib.ufunclike"             "numpy.lib.type_check"           
[133] "numpy.lib.scimath"               "numpy.lib.stride_tricks"        
[135] "numpy.lib.twodim_base"           "numpy.linalg._umath_linalg"     
[137] "numpy.linalg.linalg"             "numpy.linalg"                   
[139] "numpy.matrixlib.defmatrix"       "numpy.matrixlib"                
[141] "numpy.lib.histograms"            "numpy.lib.function_base"        
[143] "numpy.lib.index_tricks"          "numpy.lib.nanfunctions"         
[145] "numpy.lib.shape_base"            "numpy.lib.polynomial"           
[147] "textwrap"                        "numpy.lib.utils"                
[149] "numpy.lib.arraysetops"           "_weakrefset"                    
[151] "weakref"                         "numpy.lib.format"               
[153] "numpy.lib._datasource"           "numpy.lib._iotools"             
[155] "numpy.lib.npyio"                 "numpy.lib.arrayterator"         
[157] "numpy.lib.arraypad"              "numpy.lib._version"             
[159] "numpy.lib"                       "numpy.fft._pocketfft_internal"  
[161] "numpy.fft._pocketfft"            "numpy.fft.helper"               
[163] "numpy.fft"                       "numpy.polynomial.polyutils"     
[165] "numpy.polynomial._polybase"      "numpy.polynomial.polynomial"    
[167] "numpy.polynomial.chebyshev"      "numpy.polynomial.legendre"      
[169] "numpy.polynomial.hermite"        "numpy.polynomial.hermite_e"     
[171] "numpy.polynomial.laguerre"       "numpy.polynomial"               
[173] "cython_runtime"                  "_cython_0_29_34"                
[175] "numpy.random._common"            "binascii"                       
[177] "base64"                          "_hashlib"                       
[179] "_blake2"                         "hashlib"                        
[181] "hmac"                            "_bisect"                        
[183] "bisect"                          "_random"                        
[185] "_sha512"                         "random"                         
[187] "secrets"                         "threading"                      
[189] "numpy.random.bit_generator"      "numpy.random._bounded_integers" 
[191] "numpy.random._mt19937"           "numpy.random.mtrand"            
[193] "numpy.random._philox"            "numpy.random._pcg64"            
[195] "numpy.random._sfc64"             "numpy.random._generator"        
[197] "numpy.random._pickle"            "numpy.random"                   
[199] "numpy.ctypeslib"                 "_opcode"                        
[201] "opcode"                          "dis"                            
[203] "token"                           "tokenize"                       
[205] "linecache"                       "inspect"                        
[207] "numpy.ma.core"                   "numpy.ma.extras"                
[209] "numpy.ma"                        "numpy"                          
[211] "rpytools"                        "rpycall"                        
[213] "rpytools.call"                   "rpytools.loader"                
[215] "signal"                          "rpytools.signals"               
[217] "traceback"
```

There is no matplotlib here, but it is installed on my system: installed using `sudo dnf install python3-matplotlib` (version 3.7.3).

Thanks in advance for any helpful suggestions!